# Jquery click function use element as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a script that will access the inner text of any clicked item with a class named "customclass". Note that this only targets a elements.

The problem is that the individual element that is clicked doesn't seem to be passed at all. The regular expression attached replaces spaces (if any) with underscores.

I've tried the following but none work as expected:

```
// (1)
$('a.customclass').on("click", function() {
  var inner = $(this).innerHTML.replace(/ /g, "_");
});

// (2)
$('a.customclass').on("click", function(e) {
  var inner = $(e.target).innerHTML.replace(/ /g, "_");
});

// (3)
$('a.customclass').click(function(e) {
  var inner = $(e.target).innerHTML.replace(/ /g, "_");
});

// (4)
$('a.customclass').click(function() {
  var inner = $(this).innerHTML.replace(/ /g, "_");
});
```

In every case the following error appears in the console:

> Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined.

Can anyone see the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because jQuery objects do not have an `innerHTML` property.

To achieve what you need, either use the Element object provided from `this` directly:

```
$('a.customclass').on("click", function() {
  var inner = this.innerHTML.replace(/ /g, "_");
  console.log(inner);
});
```

Or alternatively, use jQuery's `html()` method:

```
$('a.customclass').on("click", function() {
  var inner = $(this).html.replace(/ /g, "_");
  console.log(inner);
});
```

I'd also suggest you have a quick read through the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com), as even just a quick glance at the method names will give you a good idea of what they do, and what's possible.

Comment: Thanks! Using just "this' in lieu of "$(this)" fixed it immediately - thanks for the quick response